# Jenkins '/' escape character does not work when combined with an environment variable

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to do some copying to a windows VM and the following line:

C:\\Users\\my_user\\${ENV_VAR}

resolves to this path:

C:\Users\my_user${ENV_VAR}

It seems to escape the character twice, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, i had to use ////, so it becomes C:\Users\my_user\\${ENV_VAR}.